# How to clone AWS CodeCommit repository with different username?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, repository, clone

First time I tried cloning an AWS CodeCommit repository using Git Bash I was asked to provide username and password, but accidently entered a wronge username credential. Now when I rerun git clone https://... it doesn't ask me for a username anymore and I receive an error immediately. How can I fix this so that I will get asked for my username again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. For some reason, my wrong credentials got added to Windows Credential Manager. Updating username and password there resolved the issue for me.